# how to return type t from a method

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have the following method that sets a few properties of IEntity. My general idea is that i would like all of my classes that implement IEntity to use this helper. The issue is that this returns IEntity and not Type T. How would do that?

```
    public static IEntity Create(IEntity entity, Company company)
    {
        entity.Company = company;
        entity.Key = Guid.NewGuid();
        entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
        entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
        entity.ModifiedByUserName = "xxx";
        entity.CreatedByUserName = "xxx";
        return entity;
    }
```

I currently call the class from my controller like so. ( TaskOrder implements IEntity )

var taskOrder = EntityHelper.Create(TaskOrder(), company);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read about generics in C#, there's a lot of material on the web.

Here is an example based on your code:

```
public static T Create<T>(T entity, Company company) where T : IEntity
{
    entity.Company = company;
    entity.Key = Guid.NewGuid();
    entity.Created = DateTime.Now;
    entity.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    entity.ModifiedByUserName = "xxx";
    entity.CreatedByUserName = "xxx";
    return entity;
}
```